# Reading bits serially in C

Tags: c, definition

I am trying to convert a bit of code from Python to C. I have got it all working other than the section below. All the variables have been defined as `int`s. I believe the problem has to do with pointers and addresses but I can't work it out.

```
for(j=0; j<12; j++)
{
  digitalWrite(CLOCK, 1);
  sleep(0.001);
  bit = digitalRead(DATA_IN);
  sleep(0.001);
  digitalWrite(CLOCK, 0);
  value = bit * 2 ** (12-j-1);  // error
  anip = anip + value;
  printf("j:%i bit:%i value:%i anip:%i", j, bit, value, anip);
}
```

The error is `invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)`

Comment: why `**`? Want exponent? Then use - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Comment: `sleep()` takes an int parameter. sleep(0.01) won't have much effect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) function takes an integer argument and waits for the specified number of seconds.  The argument `0.001` becomes `0`, which is probably not what you want.  Instead, try [usleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep), which takes an argument that represents milliseconds.

The other answers will solve the generic problem of raising an arbitrary number to a power, or to a power of 2, but this is a very specific case.

The purpose of the loop is to read 11 bits serially from MSB to LSB and convert them into an integer.  The implementation you've shown attempts to do this by reading a bit, shifting it to the correct position, and accumulating the result into `anip`.  But there's an easier way:

```
anip = 0;
for (j=0; j<12; ++j) {
  // Pulse the CLOCK line and read one bit, MSB first.
  digitalWrite(CLOCK, 1);
  usleep(1);
  bit = digitalRead(DATA_IN);
  usleep(1);
  digitalWrite(CLOCK, 0);

  // Accumulate the bits.
  anip <<= 1;    // Shift to make room for the new bit.
  anip += bit;   // Add the new bit.

  printf("j:%i bit:%i anip:%i", j, bit, anip);
}
```

As an example, suppose the first 4 bits are `1`,`0`,`0`,`1`.  Then the output will be

```
j:0 bit:1 anip:1
j:1 bit:0 anip:10
j:2 bit:0 anip:100
j:3 bit:1 anip:1001
```

When the loop completes, `anip` will contain the value of the entire sequence of bits.  This is a fairly standard idiom for reading data serially.

Although the advice to use `uint32_t` is generally appropriate, the [C standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) defines `int` to be at *least* 16 bits, which is more than the 12 you need (including the sign bit, if `anip` is signed).  Moreover, you're probably writing this for a specific platform and therefore aren't worried about portability.

Answer (score 7):

C has no exponentiation operator, which is what I guess you do `**` for.

You can use e.g. [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) if it's okay to typecast the result from a floating point value back to an integer.

Comment: pow(2.0,(float)12-j-1); Does that seem feasible?

Comment: The base is 2, so, @Lacko, I suggest `(1 << 12-j-1)`, or directly multiply `bit` with the power of 2: `bit << 12-j-1`, no need to bother `math.h` here.

Answer (score 7):

In C, `1<<i` is the best way to raise `i` to the power of 2.

Do *not* use `ints` for bit manipulation, because they vary in size by platform. Use `uint32_t` from `/usr/include/stdint.h`.

Comment: It's not just because size varies but also because bit-shifting negative values has some platform-defined behaviour. Unsigned integer bit-shifts are fully defined and predictable so long as you know the width of the type. It's good advice to always do bit-fiddling (and anything where you need predictable overflow behaviour) in unsigned integer types.

Comment: Thank for that, now i see how to do it i just think why couldnt i have done that, so thank you very much! I will test it tonight when i get back